# How to create a materialized view in SQL where a symbol is added based on the value of another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

I have a table like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | -1 |
| B | 4 |
| C | -10 |
| D | -68 |
| E | 51 |
| F | 2 |

I have to create a materialized view in SQL with a new varchar column containing the column B value with a + symbol added when the value is positive. I want a result like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | -1 | -1 |
| B | 4 | +4 |
| C | -10 | -10 |
| D | -68 | -68 |
| E | 51 | +51 |
| F | 2 | +2 |

I tried the following but this adds a + symbol before all values:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view
as
    select column a, column b, CONCAT('+', column b)  AS column c 
    from schema.table;
```

Comment: A materialized view seems like an overkill for such a simple expression. A regular view seems like a much better choice. Or maybe even a generated column directly on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to add the positive sign only if there isn't already a negative sign. Something like:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view
as
    select columna, columnb, CASE WHEN columnb NOT LIKE '-%' THEN CONCAT('+', columnb) ELSE columnb END columnc 
    from schema.table;
```

However, I would suggest revisiting whether this is actually necessary for your actual scenario. This seems like something trivial to calculate on the fly. Typically I would expect a materialized view to be used when the calculations are complex and there are performance gains that justify the duplication and wasted space. Maybe you could use a regular view or a generated column instead.